# Подключение к удаленной базе MySQL через pymysql

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, phpmyadmin, pymysql

Помогите решить проблему с подключение к удаленному серверу MySQL при попытке подключения выдает ошибку.

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xx.xx' ([WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение)")

Сам код:

```
import pymysql.cursors
conn = pymysql.connect(host="xx.xxx.xx.xx",
                       user="users",
                       password="pass",
                       db="baza",
                       charset='utf8',
                       )
sql = "SELECT ID,Pp FROM test"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
data=cur.fetchall()
for row in data:
                print(row)

conn.commit()
```

Если проблема не в коде могли бы вы описать решение этой проблемы в `phpadmin` или в самом `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно данная ошибка указывает на то, что по указанному адресу (`host`) никто не слушает на порту 3306 (порт используемый MySQL Server по умолчанию).

Укажите явно параметр (`port=N`) в вызове `pymysql.connect()` если ваш MySQL Server сконфигурирован на нестандартный порт (отличный от 3306).

Убедитесь что вы можете подключиться к вашему MySQL Server с данной машины, используя `mysql.exe` клиент.

Comment: А если в настройках стоит 3306 , но при проверки порта на то что он закрыт или открыт вылет что он закрыт

Comment: @Дмитрий, похоже, что SQL Server не стартован или работает некорректно